# AWS EMR file creation on cluster not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, emr

I am running some shell script in EMR, when I submit the script by adding step - The process runs, but a line in the script which creates a file onto the local system. However, when I log in through SSH and ran the same script (i.e. copy and paste into command line once logged in) I am getting the file creation.

the line which creates a file is:

```
echo $FILENAMEUS > /home/hadoop/filename.csv
```

My first thoughts is ownership of the hadoop file system, but I have no real clue as to why this happens. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So you cannot simply `echo` directly onto hadoop fs, you need to use the hadoop fs -put function in order to put it there.

```
echo $FILENAME | hadoop fs -put - filesystem:///url
```

really handy, you can directly hadoop fs -put onto HDFS file system, so you could do all the `sed` `awk` etc and then -put it onto HDFS.